# generating step by step permutions with fixed order previous elements in Matlab

Tags: matlab, permutation

I want to make a permutation of digits, step by step,
first deciding whether `[1 2]` or `[2 1]`, then if `[2 1]` is accepted, deciding on the place of `3` i.e.

```
[3 2 1] or [2 3 1] or [2 1 3].
```

in other words, in each step the place of the former digits is fixed (`[2 1]` is fixed). 
how can I generate such permutations in each step?

Comment: The solution here -- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/48942-insert-element-in-vector -- can easily be adapted to do what you want.  As always with Matlab questions it's worth while consulting Matlab Central.

Comment: And are you sure you need this? Or is it something else you try to achieve using this algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
n = 10; % intended length of result    
result = 1;
for k = 2:n
    id = randi(k);
    result = [result(1:id-1) k result(id:end)];
end
```